# Noise in DC supply due to AC track nearby

Tags: voltage, pcb, ac, dc, noise

The RL_NC track in the image will carry 230V AC. Will the EMI noise from this track affect my 9V supply nearby (output of LM7809)?

I use the 9V supply to measure the voltage drop across a conducting material.

[image]

Comment: I'd be very concerned about the trace gaps when working with 230 volts. They don't look sufficient for safety.

Comment: What’s the clearance between them?

Comment: Are you crossing a low-voltage line right under your 230 V line, with but maybe 2mm to 3mm between a 230 V through hole and the via? That seems very irresponsible. Keep your 230 V section separate from your low-voltage section. Not primarily because of EMI, but because that's a way to avoid fires, and electrocuting people.

Comment: +1, noise issues are unlikely, but safety, omg

Comment: Is the board's ground connected to the mains ground? Or is the device "floating" with respect to mains ground?

Comment: @Andyaka What would be a safe spacing? I have about 5mm between the closest via and the through-holes of the relay.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The transformer isolates the mains ground with the circuit ground

Answer (score 0):

> The transformer isolates the mains ground with the circuit ground

The common mode voltage of a single phase and neutral, with respect to ground, is (close to) one half of the differential voltage between phase and neutral.

When a transformer primary is connected to a single phase and neutral, and the secondary is left "floating", then the common mode voltage on the primary is passed to the secondary, either through interwinding capacitance in the transformer, or through "Y" capacitors added to reduce EMI. That is, a "floating" secondary has a common mode AC voltage with respect to ground. The capacitative coupling between the primary and secondary is generally "small", so it's impedance is high. Thus the common mode voltage appears as a "phantom" voltage. It is measurable, but is easily brought to near zero by a low impedance to ground.

Further, if the inputs to a full-wave bridge rectifier have a common mode AC voltage with respect to ground, the outputs of that bridge rectifier will have essentially the same common mode AC voltage with respect to ground.

> Will the EMI noise from this track affect my 9V supply nearby (output of LM7809)?

I can't say one way or another how much EMI noise from the track will affect neighboring circuits. However, I can say that common mode noise will be transmitted through the transformer, unless the secondary is actually grounded, and not merely have a nominal ground *node* or a ground plane.

You may discover that your 9V circuit has noise picked up from mains power, but it may not be coming from cross-talk between traces, but through your transformer (and Y-capacitors, if present) combined with the absence of a low impedance path between your secondary circuit and (physical) ground.